# Shape of tensorflow model input

Tags: natural-language, lstm, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, transformers

I'm reading [Masking and padding with Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding), in the beginning, an input example is:

```
[
  ["Hello", "world", "!"],
  ["How", "are", "you", "doing", "today"],
  ["The", "weather", "will", "be", "nice", "tomorrow"],
]
```

The article states:

> The data is a nested list where individual samples have length 3, 5,
> and 6, respectively. Since the input data for a deep learning model
> must be a single tensor (of shape e.g. **(batch_size, 6, vocab_size)** in
> this case)

What is this tensor's shape **(batch_size, 6, vocab_size)**?

- Is `batch_size` 3 since there're 3 sentences?
- What is `6` here? Is it the longest sentence's length?
- What is `vocab_size`?

The shape is strange to me because [`tf.keras.layers.Embedding`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding#input-shape)'s input is a "2D tensor with shape: (batch_size, input_length)." This is not the same with the above shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vocab_size` is the size of the vocabulary, the number of unique tokens. They are one-hot encoded, hence the number of columns reflect their count. `batch_size` is the number of samples you pass to a training step at a time. So the tensor is batch size by the length of the longest sentence (shorter ones are padded) by the number of unique words.

Comment: So the input tensor is of shape `(batch_size, input_length, vocab_size)`. The `vocab_size` dimension corresponds to one-hot encoding and it has the same purpose as `tf.keras.layers.Embedding`. Is this correct?


Also, is there any particular scenario where we should use one-hot encoding like this instead of embedding (subspace embedding)? Because it seems to me once we have padded sequence of tokens, we can just input the sequence directly to embedding layer and obtain their embeddings.

Comment: @CyberPlayerOne sure, the data could be embeddings, hash-encodings, etc just the example uses raw data here.